# jest-resolve nested module resolving wrong path: Cannot find module 'react-dnd' from 'reactTags.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I have a module I am trying to test. That module is using other external modules and jest is having a hard time resolving them.

It is resolving the base path to:
*./node_modules/react-tag-input/dist-modules/*

Instead of:
*./node_modules/react-tag-input/node_modules/react-dnd*

Below, is a simplified version of what is happening:

**Error:**

```
Cannot find module 'react-dnd' from 'reactTags.js'

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:160:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-tag-input/dist-modules/reactTags.js:13:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/tagger/eventtagger.js:5:404)
```

This is my test file:
**caseevent.test.js**

```
import EventTagger from './eventtagger.js';
```

**eventtagger.js**

```
import ReactTags from 'react-tag-input';
```

**package.json**

```
"jest": {
   "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
   ],
   "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>"
   ],
},
"dependencies": {
   "babel-jest": "^17.0.2",
   "flux": "^2.0.1",
   "install": "^0.8.1",
   "jest": "^17.0.3",
   "lodash.flow": "^3.3.0",
   "npm": "^3.10.6",
   "object-assign": "^1.0.0",
   "react": "^15.4.0",
   "react-dnd": "git+https://github.com/jcrogel/react-dnd.git",
   "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.0.0",
   "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
   "react-tag-input": "^4.4.0",
   "react-tagcloud": "^0.6.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
   "babel-cli": "^6.9.0",
   "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
   "babel-eslint": "^4.1.3",
   "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
   "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
   "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
   "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.0.15",
   "babel-register": "^6.9.0",
   "chai": "^3.5.0",
   "enzyme": "^2.6.0",
   "jest-cli": "^17.0.3",
   "jsdom": "^9.4.0",
   "lodash": "4.14.1",
   "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.0",
   "react-native": "^0.38.0",
   "react-test-renderer": "15.4.0",
   "sinon": "^1.17.4",
   "webpack": "^1.13.1",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
   "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.1"
 }
```

What am I missing? How do I get jest-resolve to find or mock deeper components?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue as well. Some things I've attempted:

jest.unmock(module) at the top of the testing file
polyfill the module in a Jest setup file
jest.mock(jest.fn() => {console.log('do something'))
Lastly, and this seemed to work, but I can't find documentation on this:

At the top of the testing file:

/**
* @providesModule moduleName
*/

This seems to recognize the module I needed. Jest is supposed to implicitly see modules out of the box, but I haven't had that experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my jest tests, with an external dependency of webpack.

To solve that:

1. I create a __mocks__ folder in the same level if __test__ folder.
2. Inside that, I created a file with the same name of the dependency, in my case it was jquery ($.js).
3. Inside my test file, I use jest.mock function to reference the mock external dependency: jest.mock('$');

from jest the docs:
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html

Hope it could help.